# Upgrading pip3 for newer python version

Tags: python, pip

I upgraded python from 3.6.1 to 3.9.2. However, and when I check the pip3 version, it's still using the old python:

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 21.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

My objective would be to upgrade pip but, more importantly, that pip3 pointed to `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip` in order to use the upgraded python.
P.S. Erasing and reinstalling pip3 did not work, it still takes the old python3.

Comment: What does your $PATH contain?

Comment: Check out this discussion https://askubuntu.com/a/1187369 basically instead of using `pip install <package-name>` use  `python<version-code> -m pip install <package-name>`

Comment: The system is running on CentOS8. The PATH has /home/centos/.local/bin:/home/centos/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin. The output from python3 -m pip --version is
pip 20.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9), but pip3 --version is still pointing to 3.6.